# How to take map to particular element after map and split?

Tags: split, functional-programming, d

Having the following snippet:

```
import std.algorithm;
import std.array : split;
import std.stdio;
import std.file;
import std.range;

void main(string[] args)
{
    string filename = "file.log";
    string term = "action";
    auto results = File(filename, "r")
                    .byLine
                    .filter!(a => canFind(a, term))
                    .map!(a => splitter(a, ":"));
                    // now how to take only first part of split? up to first ':'?

    foreach (line; results)
        writeln(line);
}
```

I am only interested in the first part after split operation (or some other operation that might be more efficient - just find first `:` and extract all characters up to it).

I tried something like:

```
.map!(a => a[0])
```

after split but I got an error

```
main.d(37): Error: no [] operator overload for type Result
/usr/include/dmd/phobos/std/algorithm/iteration.d(488):        instantiated from here: MapResult!(__lambda4, MapResult!(__lambda3, FilterResult!(__lambda2, ByLine!(char, char))))
main.d(37):        instantiated from here: map!(MapResult!(__lambda3, FilterResult!(__lambda2, ByLine!(char, char))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [until](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_searching.html#.until).

`.map!(a => a.until(':'));`

`group`'s default comparison is `a == b`, which does not work on lazy Untils. To use it with `group`, you need to pass a comparison that works, which would be [equal](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_comparison.html#.equal.equal):

```
    .map!(a => a.until(':'))
    .group!equal
    ...
```

Comment: replacing `.map!(a => splitter(a, ":").front)` with `.map!(a => a.until(':'))` somehow messes up my results: I get unsorted data (while giving sorted as input).

Comment: That might be caused by the instability of byLine's result, you could try `a => a.idup.until(':')`

Comment: What's the test data and expected output?

Comment: You can check it here: https://dpaste.dzfl.pl/48e3ad66eefc. if you change the commented `splitter` line you will get the correct results (grouped)

Comment: It looks like group doesn't work that well with a list of lazy ranges, hmm ... `a.until(':').array` seems to work.

Comment: Oh OK. I guess I have found out as well that my previous implementation didn't work either without array ( I need to add `.array` as well to get the correct results : `.map!(a => splitter(a, ":").front.array)` ). Will you update your answer to reflect this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use
[`std.algorithm.findSplitAfter`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_searching.html#.findSplitAfter):

```
    auto results = File(filename, "r")
                    .byLine
                    .filter!(a => canFind(a, term))
                    .map!(a => a.findSplitAfter(":")[1]);
```

Another option combines [`find`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_searching.html#.find) to get you to the `:` and [`drop`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#.drop) to get you past it:

```
auto results = File(filename, "r")
                .byLine
                .filter!(a => canFind(a, term))
                .map!(a => a.find(":").drop(1));
```

Comment: It's not `findSplitAfter...[1]` but `findSplitBefore...[0]` I was looking for. The drop doesn't work as I wanted (it extracts the part after `:` not before)

Comment: In your question, "first part after split" and "find : and cut all characters up to it" sound like you want the part after `:`

Comment: Sorry, I might have used wrong wording. I corrected that now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I can also use `splitter.front`

```
auto results = File(filename, "r")
                .byLine
                .filter!(a => canFind(a, term))
                .map!(a => splitter(a, ":").front);
```

(any idea if there is something like indexing operator besides the `front`?)

Comment: `splitter` is lazily evaluated and doesn't support random indexing. You'd have to advance the range using `drop`: `splitter(a, ":").drop(1).front`